# How to implement strictNullChecks in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, strictnullchecks

I have tried to implement `strictNullChecks` in angular 4 application.

I have just added  `"strictNullChecks": true`  in `tsconfig.json`

When I run the application `ng serve` I got this below error.

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/forms/src/model.d.ts:244:39 
TS2459: Type '{ onlySelf?: boolean | undefined; emitEvent?: boolean | 
undefined; } | undefined' has no property 'emitEvent' and no string index signature.
```

> What's going wrong? How can we implement `strictNullChecks` in angular 4?

Comment: Angular 4.x does not support `strictNullChecks`, so I think you have to wait for Angular 5. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15432 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16357 and probably several others. (Note the first linked issue says fixed in 4.1, the second says still not fixed in 4.1 but has been closed as a duplicate of the first)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Angular 2.x-4x

When you enable `strictNullChecks`, it enables it for all TypeScript files, which includes libraries.

To enable `strictNullChecks` in an Angular CLI project set `skipLibCheck` to true in your tsConfig.

### Angular 5.x+ has addressed this issue.